# QTimeZone::QTimeZone(int offsetSeconds)

Tags: qt

I am using Qt 5.4.1 and getting issue during calling QTimeZone::QTimeZone(int offsetSeconds) method. My code is :

```
QTimeZone zone =  QTimeZone(+19800); // +19800 is offsetFromUtc in seconds for India country
qDebug()<<QLocale::countryToString(zone.country());
```

The above qDebug prints "Default" each time but when I am using     QTimeZone(const QByteArray & ianaId) method for example :

```
 QTimeZone zone =  QTimeZone("Asia/Calcutta");
 qDebug()<<QLocale::countryToString(zone.country());
```

The above qDebug prints "India" which is correct. But at the same time QTimeZone(int offsetSeconds)  method is not working properly.....could anybody help me what I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to convert a timezone offset into a country. The relationship is `1:n` from locality to offset: if you know the region/country, *and* current UTC, you can know the timezone offset. But there is a lot of different locales that have the same offset. And the offset it not necessarily constant over time for any given location.

Comment: Ok..but in that case what is the utilization of QTimeZone::QTimeZone(int offsetSeconds)  method ?  As I know both methods Creates an instance of the requested time zone...

Comment: @Yogesh The time zone is uniquely defined by the offset, so creating it by the offset is the most direct way. If you create it based on the location, it's not unique at all: the actual offset will depend **also** on the UTC, and on how current your location-to-timezone data is. Recall that such mappings change on the whim of lawmakers. Furthermore, you don't even know (neither do I) whether the data used by `QTimeZone` includes historical records. A given timezone might have different offsets on different dates (UTC timestamps, really)!